# Make continuous variable the baseline when interacting with factor variable (stata)

Tags: stata

Consider two variables `sex` and `age`, where `sex` is treated as categorical variable and `age` is treated as continuous variable. I want to specify the full factorial using the non-interacted `age`-term as baseline (the default for `sex##c.age` is to omit one of the `sex`-categories).

The best I could come up with, so far, is to write out the factorial manually (and omitting `age' from the regression):

```
reg y sex#c.age i.sex
```

This is mathematically equivalent to

```
reg y sex##c.age
```

but allows me to directly infer the regression coefficients (and standard errors!) on the interaction term `sex*age` for **both** genders.

**Is there a way to stick to the more economic "`##`" notation but make the continuous variable the omitted category?**

(I know the manual approach has little overhead notation in the example given here, but the overhead becomes huge when working with triple-interaction terms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but a workaround: One can use `lincom' to obtain linear combinations of coefficients and standard errors. E.g., one could obtain the combined effects for both sexes as follows:

```
reg y sex##c.age
forval i = 1/2 {
    lincom age + `i'.sex#c.age
    }
```